# remove charecters found after closing the last node from XML

Tags: java

How can i remove the strings found after closing of node `</note>`
   following is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>   
       <note> <to>Tove</to>
     <from>Jani</from>
     <heading>Reminder</heading>
     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
    </note>
    <!-- ID3x v4.60 (387) - X29 - 00.011.623 - base - 14/03/2012 10:44:35 - getalerts.xml -->
```

I want to remove the string' `<!-- ID3x v4.60 (387) - X29 - 00.011.623 - base - 14/03/2012 10:44:35 - getalerts.xml -->'`

Comment: Do you want to do that using plain string manipulation or using any parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Java String's replaceAll:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
xmlFileContent.replaceAll("<!--.*?-->", "");
```

Comment: how to tackle same issue in vb.net?
i have 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Note>
<to>abc</to>
<from>xyz</from>
</Note>NUL`
here in notepad++ editor it is visible as NUL in black but in EditPlus editor same is showing in new next line of </Note> but as white space.
please advise how to remove this from xml file in vb.net